# Cannot find route from IndexController file to index.php file

Tags: php, url, phalcon

I have a little problem launching index.php file witch is most important to launch a website. I downloaded whole webpage from one server and i want it to launch from XAMPP. I already have imported all databases and every server file in htdocs. Project, i suppose, is build in Phalcon Framework, thats why i have instaled Phalcon in XAMPP. Now i have stucked in this error

First part -

[image]

Second part -

[image]

which im trying to fix for days. I am not asking for you to fix this, but I am asking for suggestions or ideas to fix this problem. If you need any other codes like index.php or any other controller file, I can show you them here. This is all code from `IndexController` file.

```
<?php 
class IndexController extends ControllerBase {
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $url = str_replace('/', '', $_REQUEST['_url']);
        if ($url)
        {
            return $this->notFound();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `$_REQUEST['_url']` is not being sent into the function.  If you place `var_dump($_REQUEST);` before the line containing `$url = str_replace('/', '', $_REQUEST['_url']);` you will find it is empty.

Comment: You also have an extra `/` in your views path at `application/views//macro`

Comment: What code is on "view//macro/form.tpl" line 7? The error clearly says you are trying to use `EMPTY` which isn't expected.